# AngularJs inline value undefined and zero

Tags: angularjs

I need to show a value in AngularJS inline

```
<myTag value="entity.order || '*'") />
```

it displays me `*` when the `order == 0`, how to avoid that, setting `*` only if the order is `undefined`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's basically a one line `if` statement.

```
<myTag value="entity.order === undefined? '*': entity.order") />
```

However using ternary operators often get pretty messy in the HTML. Not the best for code maintainability but it works if it must be inline.

Answer (score 0):

```
<myTag value="entity.order | undef:'*'") />

app.filter('undef', function() {
  return function(value, undefValue) {
    return angular.isUndefined(value) ? undefValue : value;
  };
});
```

But in theory you should design things such way that null, undefined and empty string are treated same way.